# Java NIO2 ClientServer, how to expose the server outside of the local machine?

Tags: java, server, client

I'm trying to use Java Nio2 (Java7+) to write a simple ping-pong client server. It works just fine on a single machine, but If I try to get it working on two machines, or just on a single machine while using the external IP, it would not work. Here is my code; If I use line A or B as address, it works; if I use line C it fails with 
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind

```
public class CS {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    server(address).start();
    client(address).start();
    }
  public static InetSocketAddress address=
    new InetSocketAddress("10.0.1.10",2500);//A
    new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",2500);//B
    new InetSocketAddress(CS.myIP(),2500);//C
   public static Thread server(InetSocketAddress a) throws IOException{
     var server = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open();
     server.bind(a);
     return new Thread(()->{
       try(var s=server){
         Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> future = server.accept();
         var worker = future.get();
         var received=CS.readString(worker);
         System.out.println("Message received from client: " + received);
         CS.writeString(worker,"pong");
         }
       catch(InterruptedException e){
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); throw new Error(e);}
       catch(IOException|ExecutionException e){throw new Error(e);}
       });
    }
  static Thread client(InetSocketAddress a)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
    AsynchronousSocketChannel client=AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
    client.connect(a).get();
    return new Thread(()->{
      try(var c=client){
        writeString(client,"ping");
        String msg=readString(client);  
        System.out.println("Message received from server: " + msg);
        }
      catch(IOException e){throw new Error(e);}
      });
    }
  public static String readString(AsynchronousSocketChannel worker){
    ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
    try{worker.read(readBuffer).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);}
    catch(TimeoutException|InterruptedException|ExecutionException e){
      throw new Error(e);}
    return new String(readBuffer.array());    
    }
  public static void writeString(AsynchronousSocketChannel worker,String s){
    worker.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(s.getBytes()));
    }
  public static String myIP(){
    try(var stream=new URL("https://api.ipify.org").openStream();
        var s=new Scanner(stream, "UTF-8")
      ){return s.useDelimiter("\\A").next();}
    catch (IOException e){throw new Error(e);}
    }
  }
```

I also tried to make so that the client see "myIP" while the server see localhost, both with 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0; And in that case I get java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: The remote computer refused the network connection.

Comment: Bind it to 0.0.0.0, not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Hi user, I did it, but nothing changes. But thanks to your suggestion I discover I needed to call get() to wait for the connection before starting the thread. Thanks for that, I edited the question accordingly